# UIBackgroundMode remote-notification doesn't work on iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, push-notification, ios7.1

I'm having issues with the *remote-notification* background mode on iOS 7.1. I filed a bug on Radar (http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5279828798341120), which I copied below for convenience.

Anybody else experiencing this issue? Any word on Apple's end?

---

## Summary

Sending a push notification with the *content-available* tag is supposed to wake up the app in the background and call *application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler*. It works well on iOS 7.0.6, but not on iOS 7.1.1.

## Steps to Reproduce

1. Create an empty iOS application project. Launching it should display a plain white view.
2. Ask for push permissions when the app starts, and print the push token in the console.
3. In the target settings (Capabilities -> Background Modes) enable *Remote notifications*.
4. In AppDelegate, implement *application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler*. Make it change the window's background color to red and NSLog("Application did receive remote notification").
5. Run the app from Xcode (Product -> Run).
6. Close the app from Xcode (Product -> Stop).
7. Double press the Home button: the multitasking screenshot of the app shows a plain white view.
8. With a program such as nomad-cli (http://nomad-cli.com/), send a push notification to your device with the "content-available" tag (option -n with nomad-cli): the push notification should appear on the Home screen.
9. Double press the Home button and check the color of the multitasking screenshot.

## Expected Results

If the app was launched in the background and *application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler* was called, the multitasking screenshot should be red. Moreover, the console logs in the Xcode Organizer should display *Application did receive remote notification*.

## Actual Results

On iOS 7.0.6, the multitasking screenshot is indeed red. Moreover, the console logs in the Xcode Organizer display the following logs:

```
May 30 16:50:14 iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[266] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/47E7DA84-E83A-4B43-B550-7D203921BD49 (sandbox)
May 30 16:50:14 iPad Test[266] <Warning>: Application did receive remote notification
```

On iOS 7.1.1, the multitasking screenshot stays white, and the console logs in the Xcode Organizer don't display anything.

## Version

iPhone 5: iOS 7.1.1 [11D201]. iPad 2: iOS 7.0.6 [11B651].

## Configuration

iPhone 5 32GB AT&T, using WiFi. iPad 2 16GB, using WiFi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a false alert. One of the devices I used for testing had background fetch disabled in the settings (Settings -> General -> Background App Refresh). I'm closing the issue.

Comment: Hi @Alexis. Disabling 'Background App Refresh' also disables background push notification fetch functionality?

Comment: Indeed, that was my experience.